# How to get previous record from current date?

Tags: sql

I've a table which has current record as well as previous records:

```
|   PERIOD     |    START DATE      |      END DATE      | VAL1  |  VAL2 |
|   218413     | 25-JAN-19 00:00:00 | 20-MAY-19 00:00:00 |  MA   |   12  |
|   218413     | 25-JAN-19 00:00:00 | 20-MAY-19 00:00:00 |  MA   |   21  |
|   218413     | 25-JAN-19 00:00:00 | 20-MAY-19 00:00:00 |  MA   |   32  |
|   218512     | 24-JAN-19 00:00:00 | 20-MAY-19 00:00:00 |  MA   |   14  |
|   218402     | 08-AUG-18 00:00:00 | 27-DEC-18 00:00:00 |  MA   |   15  |
|   218402     | 08-AUG-18 00:00:00 | 27-DEC-18 00:00:00 |  MA   |   24  |
|   218782     | 18-APR-18 00:00:00 | 17-JUL-18 00:00:00 |  MA   |   44  |
|   218782     | 18-APR-18 00:00:00 | 17-JUL-18 00:00:00 |  MA   |   54  |
```

I am using Oracle DB. There is no fixed time gap between the end date of old records and start date of new records. 
I want to see record for the recent old PERIOD based on current PERIOD. In above example,current PERIOD is 218413 so the result should be:

```
|   218402     | 08-AUG-18 00:00:00 | 27-DEC-18 00:00:00 |  MA   |
```

if I remove VAL2 from group by.
How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: please tag the dbms being used and also your attempt.

Comment: Latest old record?

Comment: There is 2 records for the period 218402, which one should we chose ? As @VamsiPrabhala explain we can't answer until you told us wich dbms you are using and the version (MySQL 8.0, etc...)

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala I am using Oracle. Every PERIOD and VAL1 comination will have multiple VAL2 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select "PERIOD" from myTable 
where "START DATE" = 
(Select Min("START DATE") from myTable where "START DATE" > 
(select min("START DATE") from myTable))
```

Comment: @DebanjanB, it is obvious what it does, and already in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . you can use `dense_rank()` to identify the group and then `fetch first 1 row only` (or the equivalent) to get only one row:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (order by start_date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: Thanks for response Gordon. Don't think I framed my question correctly. I want to see record for the recent old PERIOD base don current PERIOD. In above example,current PERIOD is 218413 so the result should be: |   218402     | 08-AUG-18 00:00:00 | 27-DEC-18 00:00:00 |  MA   |   
if I remove VAL2 from group by.